# Pointers through an char array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm practising the concepts of pointers in C++, so I'm trying to go through a char array with a pointer to print the individual letters of this array, so I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
void printCharackter(char* str){
    for (char *ptr=str;*ptr!='\0';ptr++) {
        std::cout<<*ptr<<" ";
    }
}
int main(){
    char* str{ "Hello, world!" };
    printCharackter(str);

    return 0;
}
```

It works correctly but I think it could be written in a better way. Do you have some tips or advise, how can I improve this code? e.g. the only Idea what I got for the loop condition is the null-terminator, other Ideas?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: string literals are meant to indicate the end of the string by the null terminator, so this is the correct way to do that.
For other usecases (e.g. iterating over arrys) you would need to be given the length of the array explicitly and use indexing. Or you get a pointer to one-past-the-end and use it like iterators

Comment: `char*` -> `const char*`.

Comment: @ Jarod42, why should I make it const in this case? I mean what is the benefit of const in this case?

Comment: The reason for `const` is that `"Hello, world!"` is an array of `const char`. Back in the olden days, creating a `char*` that pointed at its first element was okay, but using that pointer to modify an element of the array resulted in undefined behavior. These days, `char *str { "Hello, world!" };` is ill-formed. It has to be `const char *str { "Hello, world!" };` because the characters in `"Hello, world!"` are not modifiable. Your compiler should have issued a diagnostic (an error message or a warning) for that code.

Comment: I would suggest `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` compiler flags at minimum. Especially if you work with pointers. Of course specify the standard too e.g. `-std=c++17`.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you man for your explanation. I got it now :)

Comment: Knowing pointers is important, so it's good that you practice with them, and discover the related pitfalls when using them. Also note that, outside of practice, for the task above one should use `std::string` (thus avoiding pointers).